# How to count column value occurrences using a list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have the list :

```
size_s = ["S", "S.", "s", "Size S.", "size S", "S(bust 88cm)", "S (waist58-62cm)", "S(Pink & Black)","Size-S",
         "S Diameter 30cm", "Size/S", "S Pink", "Size--S", "SIZE S", "US-S"]
```

and I'm trying to loop through a column in my dataframe to see which values containn the strings from my list. I'm using:

```
   count = 0

for i in df["product_variation_size_id"]:
    if df["product_variation_size_id"].contains(size_s):
        count +=1
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the data frame you are using?

Comment: product_variation_size_id
0      "S"
1      "S."
2      "SizeS
3      "SIZE S"
4      "small"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
count = len(df.loc[df["product_variation_size_id"].isin(size_s)])
```

Here is a toy example I made to test the concept:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"product_variation_size_id":["S Diameter 30cm", 'XXXXX', "SIZE S"]})

size_s = ["S Diameter 30cm","SIZE S"]


count = len(df.loc[df["product_variation_size_id"].isin(size_s)])
print(count)
2
```